# Python Xlwings – Duplicate Columns with Format

Tags: python, xlwings

I would like to create automated protocols in Excel. In VBA this works very well, you can click a button, enter the values in some input fields and the macro generates the protocols.

Now I would like to do the whole thing with Python. With Xlswriter it is certainly possible, but I would like to solve it with Xlwings, but I don't know if it is possible with that?

So far, I have managed to copy the entire contents of an Excel sheet.

```
import xlwings as xw

path_read = 'C:/Users/Public/test.xlsx'
path_write = 'C:/Users/Public/test_copy.xlsx'
wb = xw.Book(path_read)  
sht = wb.sheets[0] 
new_wb = xw.Book(path_write)    
new_wb.sheets.add("Temp", after=1) 
print(new_wb.sheets)
sht.api.Copy(Before=new_wb.sheets['Temp'].api)
new_wb.sheets['Temp'].delete()
new_wb.save(path_write)
```

However, I have several logs next to each other in one sheet.
For example, I would like to copy the first 10 columns including the format of an Excel sheet and then insert them again 2 columns further to the right with format (font, connected cells, etc.) as often as it was specified.

At the moment I plan to write the values like filename, number of copies, serial number etc. as variables in the code, but it would be nice if you could use the VBA input fields for that.

Does anyone know if this is possible with xlwings? Or would the module xlswriter be better suited for this?

Answer (score 0):

To clarify my question a bit I have attached a small screenshot of an example.

Within a spreadsheet the complete columns should be copied and changed.

Unfortunately this does not work with openpyxl because of the connected cells.
Otherwise I only find examples where single cells are copied from one spreadsheet to another.

I think that copying columns and changing them is one of the standard operations in an Excel automation, isn't it?
If someone has an idea with which modules I can easily perform such operations and make the appropriate changes I would be very grateful

[Duplication of Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQGST.png)